# .NET Core : sum the number of orders by day

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I need to calculate how many orders there are in total every day and print them in the datatable day by day. I have to perform this time allocation based on the `OrderDate` value in my table. I need to find the total number of orders for each day.

I want to do:

| Date | Total Order |
| --- | --- |
| 09.10.2022 | 45 |
| 09.11.2022 | 60 |
| 09.12.2022 | 75 |

Order class:

```
public class Order : IBaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int RestaurantId { get; set; }
    public int AddressId { get; set; }

    public int? PromotionId { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DeliveryDate { get; set; }
    public OrderStatues OrderStatus { get; set; }
    public bool DropDoor { get; set; }
    public bool RingBell { get; set; }
    public string OrderNote { get; set; }
    public OrderTypes OrderType { get; set; }
    public string PaymentType { get; set; }
    public decimal SubTotal { get; set; }
    public decimal DiscountTotal { get; set; }
    public decimal OrderTotal { get; set; }
    public decimal DeliveryCost { get; set; }

    public OrderSources OrderSource { get; set; }
    public OrderTimes OrderTime { get; set; }
    public OrderDays OrderDay { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int[] SelectedProducts { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int OrderHour { get; set; }

    public virtual Restaurant Restaurant { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
    public virtual Promotion Promotion { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<JoinOrderProduct> JoinOrderProducts { get; set; } = new HashSet<JoinOrderProduct>();

    public void Build(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<Order>(entity =>
        {
            entity
            .HasKey(p => new { p.OrderId});

            entity
          .HasOne(p => p.Restaurant)
          .WithMany(p => p.Orders)
          .HasForeignKey(p => p.RestaurantId)
          .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            entity
           .Property(p => p.SubTotal)
           .HasPrecision(18, 4)
           .IsRequired();

            entity
           .Property(p => p.DiscountTotal)
           .HasPrecision(18, 4)
           .IsRequired();

            entity
           .Property(p => p.OrderTotal)
           .HasPrecision(18, 4)
           .IsRequired();

            entity
       .Property(p => p.DeliveryCost)
       .HasPrecision(18, 4)
       .IsRequired();

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Which problems do you have with `GroupBy` and `Count`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to find the total number of orders for each day.

I assume that if two `Order` objects ahave the same value for property `Order.OrderDate.Date`, that you define them as two orders on the same day.

In this case, you have to group your Orders. Each group consists of Orders that are on one date, = that have the same value for property `Order.OrderDate.Date`. Once you have these groups, you can count the number of Orders in each group, to know the number of Orders on that date.

For this I use the overload of [Enumerable.GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-groupby-3(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-1))-system-func((-0-2)))) that has a parameter `resultSelector`. I use the resultSelector to convert the groups into the values that you want.

```
IEnumerable<Order> orders = ...

// make groups of Orders that have the same order date
var result = orders.GroupBy(order => order.OrderDate.Date,

// parameter resultSelector: use the key (= the common date for all Orders in the group
// and all Orders in the group, to specify the requested output
(commonOrderDate, ordersWithThisDate) => new
{
    Date = commonOrderDate,
    TotalOrder = ordersWithThisDate.Count(),
});
```

In words: from each `order` in your sequence of `Orders`, calculate the value of `order.OrderDate.Date` (= key). Make groups of `Orders` that have the same key value. For each key-group combination (= common value + Orders that have this common value), make one resulting object. This resulting object has two properties:

- Date: the common value of all Orders in the group
- TotalOrder: the number of Orders in this group. This is the number of Orders that were place on this Date.

Comment: Not `Enumerable.GroupBy`, but `Queryable.GroupBy` and I'm not sure that overload that you have chosen is translatable by EF Core.

Comment: Oh? You mean that datatable is in a different process like a database? I thought it was a local object of class `System.Data.DataTable`. In that case, if you know that if the table contains only Orders, then of course you have a method to extract the Orders in the datatable as an `IEnumerable<Order>`

Comment: Thank you Harald. Here is the solution that worked for me.